# How to fold a Repa array into an arbitrary value?

Tags: haskell, repa

All the reduction functions of [Repa](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa) fold back into the same types as the array contents. For example:

```
foldAllP :: (Shape sh, Source r a, Elt a, Unbox a, Monad m) => (a -> a -> a) -> a -> Array r sh a -> m a
foldAllS :: (Shape sh, Source r a, Elt a, Unbox a) => (a -> a -> a) -> a -> Array r sh a -> a
```

I'd like to fold a repa array into an data structure that I can pass to a GUI library to render, i.e. an arbitrary value, but I cannot find a function in the library to do this. Does this function exist or do I have to iterate over cells using `[... | x <- [0..w-1], y <- [0..h-1]]` ?

Comment: Do you have a specific example of what you want to do?

Comment: You could use the `hmatrix-repa` package to convert to an `hmatrix` array which is a no-op conversion to a C-type array.  Or you could just copy the code from `hmatrix-repa` it is that small.

Comment: Folding repa arrays only makes sense if the function is associative and the zero value must be the left and right identity, because the functions `foldAllP` and `foldAllS` make no guarantee in terms of the order in which elements are associated. In fact, `foldAllP` could freely pick a *different* association on each invocation.

Comment: @ErikR I inferred the reason already. My Repa array has info meant for graphical display, and I would like to fold it into a data structure that I can pass to graphics library. At the moment I'm using gloss.

Comment: If you have a specific example we could help you write the most efficient code. List comprehensions are not always the fastest way to iterate through a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Repa does not allow you to fold in any particular direction, because during parallel computation:

> `foldAllP`: Applications of the operator are associated arbitrarily.

On the other hand, folding sequentially should not impose a restriction on the accumulator to be of the same type as array elements, but unfortunately it is also the case with `foldAllS`.

There is a very easy workaround through falling back onto underlying vector package, namely convert a repa array to an unboxed vector using `toUnboxed` and then simply use [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) package functionality. Which, obviously, means folding will not be done in parallel, but it will still be much faster than using lists. Example:

```
λ>  import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
λ> :t V.foldr
V.foldr :: Unbox a => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Vector a -> b
λ> :t V.foldl
V.foldl :: Unbox b => (a -> b -> a) -> a -> Vector b -> a
λ> V.foldr ((&&) . (>0.5)) True $ toUnboxed repaArray
```